# How to only remove the default button Close in Fom StatusBar?

Tags: forms, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

how to remove the only Button close (default button) in the Form , in Dynamics AX-2012?

This button is located on the lower right , named "Close"

But I don't want to remove all others informations in StatusBar.

Thanks, 
enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Close" button is part of a status bar on a form.

Change `StatusBarStyle` property of the form Design to `SimpleWithoutClose` value.

**Update:**

It seems like there is no option to remove the "Close" button without leaving all other parts of "Full" status bar style.

Comment: Thanks, but Iif I use this way I delete all information also another things

Comment: Well, as long as there is no `FullWithoutClose` option, I think it is not possible at all.

Comment: Maxim, where is this FullWithoutClose  ?

Comment: There is **no** such option. That is why you cannot remove the "Close" button without removing everything that is in "Full" style.

Comment: Thanks, I did'd understand well !
But I need that information (such AOS name etc), from code I got the same result.

In my Form init method:  

` element.design().statusBarStyle(4);` 

for you it's possible to set more specifically from code?
Thanks for your time!